# How to draw a circle with "venn diagram intersection diamond"

Tags: diagrams

I am wondering how to draw the below picture using tikz

[image]

The purple part is a venn diagram intersection diamond (sorry I can't think of the better term). I know how to draw a circle but I am not sure how to draw that diamond. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add circle arcs and fill the region in between to draw that diamond.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick, fill=blue!40] (0,0) circle (2);
    \draw[very thick, fill=purple!60] (120:2)
        arc[start angle=60, end angle=-60, radius=2]
        arc[start angle=240, end angle=120, radius=2];
    \node at (180:1) {AB};
    \node at (0:1) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```